# Intellij Idea css error tips

Tags: css, intellij-idea

In MyEclipse, the CSS file is compiler success! But when I import my code to IntelliJ Idea. I got the Compile error.

How can I close the error tips?

[image]

Comment: I can't seem to find the official definition for alternating-row-colors, but as a hunch I'd say try removing the comma.

Comment: Try `alt+enter` on the error. IntelliJ should show you possible ways how to resolve the issue. However, I have never heard about `alternating-row-colors` rule (I can't even find any documentation for it.)

Comment: @MartinVseticka  thanks martin & Lister,I have resolved this problem,change run or debug configuration.`Run ->Edit Configurations->Make,no error check` By the way,the`alternatingRowColors` is style of `Apache Flex DataGrid`.